# Starting steam on Startup minimized

Tags: startup, steam, minimize

Is there a way to start steam on boot minimized (or in tray) just like on windows, so the window wont pop into my face every time I boot up UBUNTU?

Answer (score 1):

Add `-silent` as a parameter to the desktop file for steam.

It will be in one of these:

```
/usr/share/applications/ 
/usr/local/share/applications/
~/.local/share/applications/
```

The last one takes priority if present.

Or, in KDE, go to System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Autostart, and add an entry for steam. In the application menu, use `-silent %U` as the arguments.

Comment: How do I add --silent as a parameter?

Comment: put it in the desktop file behind the line that has the steam executable

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the top result on Google for 'linux start steam minimized' I'll add that on my Arch+KDE system, Steam prefers `-silent` rather than the POSIX-compliant `--silent`